# Non-blocking response from HTTP server in Android

Tags: android, http, sockets, nio, httpserver

I have implemented HTTP server(handling GET. POST and DELETE requests) in Android using sockets. In order to make the server non-blocking, I saw there is

```
java.nio
```

package http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/package-summary.html. However, the selector keys are accept, read or write. Is there any example link or tutorial of how will I implement non-blocking server using nio for each of the methods mentioned?

Note: Http Core cannot be used as Android does not support org.apache.http.nio.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused here about what you are asking. Are you looking for some library that would do HTTP for you over non-blocking sockets? Something like http://code.google.com/p/rupy/ or http://www.simpleframework.org/?

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov Thanks for your reply. Currently in my server side, I am handling each HTTP method using request.getRequestLine().getMethod(). But I am confused, how can I implement the same with non-blocking capability(using java.nio). Looking for an example.

Comment: I don't have a ready example for you, but the concept is rather different. You wait on a selector, read chunk of input, parse/buffer it, then invoke some callback when you have enough data (like complete message header), callbacks trigger events on some *protocol state machine*. Start with existing tutorials like http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/ to get some overview.

Comment: Ok. In my case, clients use the same request URLs for each of the method. Right now my server is developed using Apache CORE. The requests are sent from Mozilla Poster and not from a NIOClient. Is this okay?

Comment: It doesn't matter what library, or even language, your clients are implemented with as long as they implement the same protocol (HTTP here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.integratingstuff.com/2011/10/24/adding-a-webserver-to-an-android-app/ gives an example of Android Web server and link http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpServer.java explains multi-threaded server. As the number of clients is only 10, I used threading.